# Can't figure out why lapply statement is producing NaNs when producing sample proportions for a list of dataframe names in R?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, lapply

I made a function, "visibilityProportionODV", that produces the sample proportion of a binary variable x$ODV where "x" is some data frame in the list "dfnames." The variable ODV contains values 1, 0, or missing (NA). I am attempting to apply my list of data frames to my function which outputs the sample proportion. I have verified that the function works outside of the lapply function by plugging in specific data frames for "x." Yet I am still getting an output of NaNs within the lapply function. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

```
namesToProportionFct <- function(x) {
  x$ODV <- as.integer(x$ODV)
  numNA <- length(x$ODV[which(is.na(x$ODV) == TRUE)])
  prop <- sum(x$ODV, na.rm = TRUE) / (length(x$ODV) - numNA)
  return(prop)
}

visibilityProportionODV <- lapply(dfnames, namesToProportionFct)

# Output:
> visibilityProportionODV
[[1]]
[1] NaN

[[2]]
[1] NaN

[[3]]
[1] NaN

[[4]]
[1] NaN

[[5]]
[1] NaN

[[6]]
[1] NaN

[[7]]
[1] NaN

[[8]]
[1] NaN

[[9]]
[1] NaN

[[10]]
[1] NaN
```

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Your function and lapply work fine for me using the following dummy list of data.frames:

```
dfnames <- list(
  data.frame(ODV=rep(sample(c(1,0,NA)),100)),
  data.frame(ODV=rep(sample(c(1,0,NA)),100)) 
)
```

Can you provide a similar list of data.frames that recreates the NaNs?

Comment: `> G1V$ODV
  [1]  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  1
 [53]  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0
[105]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 NA  1  1  1  1  1` This is the ODV vector for one of the datasets. The other 9 are similar to this just with different combinations of 1's, 0's, and NA's.

Comment: Update: I have it working now for a subset of the data frames which is acceptable for my purposes. Thank you!